# The Jacobi nome $q$

Tags: soft-question, terminology, math-history, elliptic-functions

Does anyone know why $q = e^{-\pi K'/K} = e^{\pi i \tau}$ is called the *nome*? Is there a historical reason? Does the word *nome* mean something in Latin or German?

Comment: *Nome* in Italian means *Name*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nome, from the ancient Greek νομός (nomos), from νέμειν (nemein, “to divide”). I imagine this is the [etymology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nome#Etymology).

A little more from Wikipedia, $K$ and $iK'$ are the quarter periods and $\tau=iK'/K$ is called the half-period ratio, which seems to me a division.